# Unable to start sonarqube 6.1

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

Installed the sonarqube 6.1,
Set the JAVA_HOME as C:\JDK\jdk1.8.0_92  in StartSonar.bat file and added C:\JDK\jdk1.8.0_92\bin in path variable also

When trying to start getting the below error

```
Setting JAVA_HOME
PATH: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System3
2\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program  Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\svnrepository\bin;
C:\SVN\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Sonar\sonar-runner-2.0\bin;C:\JDK\jdk1.7
.0_60\bin;C:\ANT\ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\JDK\jdk1.8.0_9
2/bin;
JAVA_HOME: C:\JDK\jdk1.8.0_92
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class    org.sonar.application.Ap
p: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/application/App :   Unsupport
 ed major.minor version 52.0
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
jvm 1    |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class}   [app_arguments]
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Where:
jvm 1    |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
jvm 1    |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
jvm 1    |                   application.
jvm 1    | Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run a class compiled with Java 8  on an older version of the JVM.  Is that Tanuki wrapper honouring the JAVA_HOME variable that you set?  What happens if you run it without going through the wrapper?

See here: [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Edit:  Also, I see that your path refers to both JDK 1.7 and JDK 1.8.  I would try to remove the reference to JDK 1.7 to see if that makes a difference.